# How can a custom-validator know which commandButton was clicked

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, myfaces

my form has several "submit" buttons,
and the validation of some of the fields depends on which was pressed.
How can I find that out in my custom validator?

Comment: are u using aspx or php html?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The button's client ID get also generated as `name` of the `<input type="submit">`. The `name=value` of the pressed `<input type="submit">` get also sent as request parameters. So you could just check for that in the request parameter map.

E.g.

```
<h:form id="formId">
    ...
    <h:commandButton id="button1" ... />
    <h:commandButton id="button2" ... />
</h:form>
```

with the following in `validate()` implementation:

```
Map<String, String> params = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

if (params.containsKey("formId:button1")) {
    // Button 1 is pressed.
}
else if (params.containsKey("formId:button2")) {
    // Button 2 is pressed.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For JSF there will be inbuilt validation messages which will get displayed during Errors..or you can use Validation attributes like "validator & validatorMessages " in primefaces in their respective Tags.

Comment: Sorry for being imprecise: I was referring to a custom validator. I'll update the subject of my question.