# Parent UIInput is not converted/validated when immediate="true" is set on <f:ajax>

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I observed following behaviour in JSF:

A UIInput component triggered via AjaxBehaviour with 'immediate=true' does not have the validator executed in the APPLY_REQUEST, but always in the Phase determined by the UIInput itself. It means the AjaxBehaviour 'immediate' attribute has no effect on when the validator of the component is processed. Which is IMO not what the describtion of AjaxBehaviour says:

> The immediate attribute indicates whether user inputs are to be processed early in the application lifecycle or later. If the attribute is set to true, events generated from this component are broadcast during the Apply Request Values phase. Otherwise, the events will be broadcast during the Invoke Applications phase.

To be read at: [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkace.html#gkhwm)

Even thought in AjaxBehaviour.isImmediate(component,behaviour) JSF takes care of having the AjaxBehaviour more important than the component

```
private boolean isImmediate(UIComponent component, AjaxBehavior ajaxBehavior) {
    boolean immediate = false;

    if(ajaxBehavior.isImmediateSet()) {
        immediate = ajaxBehavior.isImmediate();
    } else if(component instanceof EditableValueHolder) {
        immediate = ((EditableValueHolder)component).isImmediate();
    } else if(component instanceof ActionSource) {
        immediate = ((ActionSource)component).isImmediate();
    }

    return immediate;
}
```

Whereas in the UIInput.processDecodes(context) does not trigger the validation in that phase because the component is not 'immediate' ..

```
public void processDecodes(FacesContext context) {

    if (context == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    // Skip processing if our rendered flag is false
    if (!isRendered()) {
        return;
    }

    super.processDecodes(context);

    if (isImmediate()) {
        executeValidate(context);
    }
}
```

Anyways; to reproduce my case:
A) The JSF code:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="mandatory" value="#{currentQuestion.mandatory}" label="#{texts.mandatory_Question}" disabled="#{!bean.metadata.editable}" validator="mandatoryValidator" onchange="makeDirty()" immediate="false">
  <f:ajax event="click" execute="@this" render="@this :mandatory-msg" immediate="true"/>
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<h:outputLabel for="mandatory" value="#{texts.mandatory_Question}" styleClass="standard-label chkBox-label" />
<p:message for=":mandatory" id="mandatory-msg" showDetail="true" showSummary="true" />
```

B)The custom validator:

```
@FacesValidator("mandatoryValidator")
public class MandatoryValidator implements Validator {
/** logger. */
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MandatoryValidator.class.getName());

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public final void validate(final FacesContext context, final UIComponent component, final Object value) {
    if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES) {
        LOG.debug("apply phase");
    }
    if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.PROCESS_VALIDATIONS) {
        LOG.debug("validation phase");
}
}
```

In that example the validator will not be executed in the APPLY_REQUEST until the SelectBoolCheckBox is also 'immediate=true'. Even worse, the immediate of the component, even defaulted, always wins. Which makes the AjaxBehaviour immediate attribute totally worthless.

Can anyone explain or reproduce or grunt with me?

Comment: Also works with plain PF3.5 and any other UIInput like <h:inputText />

Comment: Why are you using `<f:ajax immediate="true">` in first place? What problem exactly are you trying to solve with it? It's in the context of this requirement indeed totally worthless. Just omit it. You've already an `execute="@this"` in case you're interested in processing only the current component. Or, are you in some way concretely asking for real world appliances of `<f:ajax immediate="true">`?

Comment: I would like to make a difference in the type of validation depending on whether the user clicked the component or has sent the form including the component. To be precise, the user has a heavy form and the selecBoolcheckBox must check several constraints in the model (the bean). Now if the user just clicks the selectbox, only the most important of the constraints is checked and one validation error might be displayed instantly, whereas if the form is submitted all validation shall take place to show him, how much work there is still to be done.  So that is in fact my real world application.

Comment: BTW I cannot imagine how to use the 'immediate' attribute of f:ajax if the component overrides it. IMO the last if-clause should be somehow using the first isImmediate(component,behaviour) on itself and its ajax child.

Comment: Hmm, that makes indeed sense. This behavior is then indeed unintuitive. I'd post an issue report on Mojarra tracker and see what they say on this. It's quite possible that this is an oversight/cornercase in the spec. As to the concrete functional requirement, this is maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428899/how-can-a-custom-validator-know-which-commandbutton-was-clicked/10433198#10433198

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will vote that issue, if possible.